# For a bridge, What is the difference between port & interface?

Tags: networking, 18.04, interface

Below command:

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
~$ 
~$
~$
~$
~$ sudo ovs-vsctl add-br bridge1
~$ sudo ovs-vsctl show
ab9fb6c9-69e5-4a60-84d1-94da5a66b4e2
   Bridge "mybridge"
        Port "mybridge"
            Interface "mybridge"
                type: internal
    ovs_version: "2.9.5"
~$
~$
~$
```

---

creates two new layer 2 interfaces (`ovs-system` & `bridge1`), as shown below:

```
~$ 
~$ 
~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ff:ff:ff:19:f1:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:0b:a9:0f:ff:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.68.103/24 brd 192.168.68.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 6717sec preferred_lft 6717sec
    inet6 fe80::6ce4:7dff:7ff8:3fff/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: ovs-system: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6e:ed:1a:5e:a7:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: mybridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:21:d4:14:9f:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
~$ 
~$ 
~$
```

---

1. What is `ovs-system` in the above list of interfaces?
2. What is the different between port(`Port "mybridge"`) & interface(`Interface "mybridge"`) of  a bridge(`Bridge "mybridge"`)? in the below diagram..

[image]

Comment: @guiverc Updated the query... my bad